# Design Volleyball

Tags: discussion

## Design Volleyball

As a way of increasing community activities we've created a chatroom, [Design Volleyball](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21438/design-volleyball).

The format is very open. Come in, pick an existing image you like, and make something new from it. Can be subtle changes or substantial changes. Just get the creativity going.

We recommend stating / replying to the image you decide to work off of so others know.

Conversation, feedback, and discussion is all encouraged!

Comment: This is a really good idea; now all I need is to be able to view images from http://i.imgur.com. SE has a *fun* tag, how about something similar for GD, but with a GD twist? Submissions only in graphical format maybe?

Comment: @Christopher please go here http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/its-time-to-expand-what-gd-is-about and suggest the [tag:fun] if you want to, and elaborate for those like myself that aren't familiar with the tag on SE.